# Working with Amino Acids

Tags: fasta

I am working with a file that contains thousands of proteins in an organism. I have code that will allow me to go through each individual protein one by one and determine the frequency of amino acids in each. Would there be a way to alter my current code to allow me to determine all of the frequencies of amino acids at once?

Comment: You might want to give more details on how it should look in the result. My first idea is to group your data by 'protein_location' in a dictionary and then use a list for that location with the related frequencies. But, I have no idea what you are talking about and how it actually needs to be presented to make any biological sense.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you're reinventing the wheel a bit: [BioPython](http://biopython.org/) contains utilities for handling files in various formats (FASTA in your case), and simple analysis. For your example, I'd use something like this:

```
from Bio import SeqIO    
from Bio.SeqUtils.ProtParam import ProteinAnalysis

for seq_record in SeqIO.parse("protein_x.txt", "fasta"):
    print(seq_record.id), ProteinAnalysis(repr(seq_record.seq)).get_amino_acids_percent().items()
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, but without showing us your code we can't give much feedback. Essentially you want to keep your counts of the amino acids persist between reading FASTA records. If you wanted probabilities you then total them up outside the loop and divide through only at the end. This is trivially accomplished without something like a "counting dictionary" in Python or incrementing a value in a hash/dict. There are also highly likely plenty of command line tools that do this for you since all you want is character level counts for any line not starting with a '>' in the file.

For example for a file that small:

`grep -v '^>' yourdata.fa | perl -pe 's/(.)/$1\n/g' | sort | uniq -c`